# p-value zero in hypothesis testing for survival curves

Tags: r, survival, p-value, cox-model, kaplan-meier

I have done survival analysis. I used Kaplan-Meir to do the survival analysis.

Description of data: 
My data set is large and data table has close 120,000 records of survival information belong to 6 groups.

Sample:

```
   user_id   time_in_days   event total_likes total_para_length group
1:       2          4657     1       38867        431117212   AA
2:       2          3056     1       31392        948984460   BB
3:       2            49     1          15            67770   CC
4:       3          4181     1       15778        379211806   BB
5:       3            17     1           3            19032   CC
6:       3          2885     1       12001        106259666   EE
```

After fitting the survival curves and plotting it, I see they are similar but yet at any given point in time their survival proportions don't seem to look like identical.

Here is the plot:
[image: Survival Curves]

I ran a hypothesis test where my H0: There is not difference between the survival curves and here is the results that I got.

```
> survdiff(formula= Surv(time, event) ~ group, rh=0)
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ group, rho = 0)

             N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
group=FF 28310    27993    28632      14.3      19.0
group=AA 64732    63984    67853     220.6     460.1
group=BB 19017    18690    16839     203.4     245.6
group=CC  9687     9536     8699      80.6      91.0
group=DD 13438    13187    11891     141.3     164.2
group=EE  3910     3847     3324      82.4      89.7

 Chisq= 788  on 5 degrees of freedom, p= 0
```

I am little confuse by trying to figure out what it means, specially since I got `p-value=0`.

I am fairly new to survival analysis so after reading and digging through I realized that this is a non-parametric as I understand which means that it doesn't make any assumptions of the underline distributions of the time.

After reading about cox-proportional hazard function and going over [c-cran pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-cox-regression.pdf) I performed a cox regression test and here is what I got from that:

```
> cox_model <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ X)
> summary(cox_model)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ X)

  n= 139094, number of events= 137237 

         coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)       z Pr(>|z|)    
X1 -7.655e-05  9.999e-01  1.504e-06 -50.897   <2e-16 ***
X2 -1.649e-10  1.000e+00  5.715e-11  -2.886   0.0039 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

   exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
X1    0.9999          1    0.9999    0.9999
X2    1.0000          1    1.0000    1.0000

Concordance= 0.847  (se = 0.001 )
Rsquare= 0.111   (max possible= 1 )
Likelihood ratio test= 16307  on 2 df,   p=0
Wald test            = 7379  on 2 df,   p=0
Score (logrank) test = 4628  on 2 df,   p=0
```

My big X is generated by doing rbind on total_like and total_para_length. Looking at Rsquare and P-Values I am not sure what really is going on here. If I can't throw away the Null-Hypothesis I should give a larger p-value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your $p$-value is not actually zero, it's just very close to it. If you look at your test statistics ($\chi^{2}=788$ in the Kaplan-Meier model, and the Wald $\chi^{2}=7379$ in the CPH model) they are *ginormous!* Just really, *really* big. So the associated $p$-values are tiny.

But perhaps you wonder why, if your survival curves were so similar visually, you get such a significant difference with these tests? If so, consider: even tiny differences can  obtain miniscule $p$-values if the sample size is large enough. And how big is your sample? It's about 120,000 observations: *big*! So you might expect that even very small differences will be found "significant."

What can you do with this inference, given that it is probably just telling you that you've a giant sample? I'm not sure, because I don't know if there's an equivalence test available for your two quantities. If there *is* an equivalence test for your estimates, you might (1) decide *a priori* what a *relevant difference* is (i.e. how large a difference between two groups needs to be, in order for you to care), (2) conduct  a test of difference between your two groups, (3) conduct a test of *equivalence* using your definition of relevant difference, and (4) *combine* the inferences from these test approaches which will give you an idea of whether the significant difference you are finding is *relevant* (i.e. you rejected a test for difference, but did not reject a test for equivalence) or *trivial* (you rejected a test for difference and also rejected a test for equivalence).

Comment: good answer, what you are seeing here is consistency at work: the power of a test goes to 1 as samples size goes to infinity; or p-values go to 0 as sample size goes to infinity. Another way this has been discussed is clinical significance vs statistical significance.

Comment: @Alexis I added a plot to give a better view of whats going on.

Comment: @Alexis any chance you can give explanation of what we can take out from median of the survival model.

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon I am not sure I follow your last comment. Are you inquiring about *interpretation* of the median survival time?